# cancleAnimationFrame is not stopping animation loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I tried to clone Flappy Bird and when the user collides i want to stop the animation frame and display page with last score and button . i tried this

```
function render(){
jumpCheck();
drawMovePipes();
writeScore();
interval=requestAnimationFrame(render)  
}
```

and i begin the window by hiding the startscreen and showing the game frame when clicked

```
$('startScreen').onclick=()=>{
    screen.canvas.style.display="block";
    $('startScreen').style.display="none";
     interval=window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

When collison has happened this function is called

```
function collided(){

    cancelAnimationFrame(interval);
    screen.canvas.style.display="none";
    $('h3').innerText+=`Last Score ${score}`
    $('startScreen').style.display="block";
}
```

here the problem is the loop runs constantly and keeps adding the “last Score” text repeatedly . how to completely break from the loop like game pause or exit .
The full code is at https://github.com/whatevea/FlappyBirdJS
Demo is at https://whatevea.github.io/FlappyBirdJS/Flappy%20Bird/

Comment: i tried your approach but unfortunately it didn't work for me. if the loop is only intiated by clicking the startScreen and the start screen is then hidden then how can there be multiple loops running. i edited the code as $('startScreen').onclick=()=>{
 screen.canvas.style.display="block";
 $('startScreen').style.display="none";
 cancelAnimationFrame(interval);
interval=window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

Comment: Right sorry... so looking at your github I now see that the actual problem is that you call that `collided()` function **before** calling `requestAnimationFrame`. So you are actually cancelling the frame that is currently being processed. You could return the result from `collided()` to early exit or simply not call requestAnimationFrame in that case, or just move that `requestAnimationFrame` at the beginning of your `render` function. Edited the duplicate link.